# Removing secretName from ingress.yaml results in dangling certificate in the K8s cluster as it doesn't automatically get deleted, any workaround?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

My ingress.yaml looks like so:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}-a
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight: "{{ .Values.canary.weight }}"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "120"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.urlFormat | quote }}
    secretName: {{ .Values.name }}-cert  // <-------------- This Line 
  ingressClassName: nginx-customer-wildcard
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.urlFormat | quote }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Values.name }}-a
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.backendPort }}
```

Assume `Values.name = customer-tls` then `secretName` will become `customer-tls-cert`.
On removing `secretName: {{ .Values.name }}-cert` the the nginx ingress start to use default certificate which is fine as I expect it to be but this also results in the `customer-tls-cert` certificate still hanging around in the cluster though unused. Is there a way that when I delete the cert from helm config it also removed the certificate from the cluster.
Otherwise, some mechanism that will will figure out the certificates that are no longer in use and will get deleted automatically ?

My nginx version is nginx/1.19.9
K8s versions:
Client Version: v1.25.2
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: v1.24.6

I experimented with --enable-dynamic-certificates a lil bit but that's not supported anymore on the versions that I am using. I am not even sure if that would have solved my problem.

For now I have just manually deleted the certificate from the cluster using `kubectl delete secret customer-tls-cert -n edge` where `edge` is the namespace where cert resides.

Edit: This is how my certificate.yaml looks like,

```
{{- if eq .Values.certificate.enabled true }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}-cert
  namespace: edge
  annotations:
    vault.security.banzaicloud.io/vault-addr: {{ .Values.vault.vaultAddress | quote }}
    vault.security.banzaicloud.io/vault-role: {{ .Values.vault.vaultRole | quote }}
    vault.security.banzaicloud.io/vault-path: {{ .Values.vault.vaultPath | quote }}
    vault.security.banzaicloud.io/vault-namespace : {{ .Values.vault.vaultNamespace | quote }}
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: {{ .Values.certificate.cert }}
  tls.key: {{ .Values.certificate.key }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Do you also create the Secret as part of the Helm chart?  How should Helm know to delete id?

Comment: Yes, I have certificate.yaml that contains the key and cert. I get what your are saying so I also asked if there is some mechanism that will will figure out the certificates that are no longer in use and will get deleted automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes in general will not delete things simply because they are not referenced.  There is a notion of ownership which doesn't apply here (if you delete a Job, the cluster also deletes the corresponding Pod).  If you have a Secret or a ConfigMap that's referenced by name, the object will still remain even if you delete the last reference to it.

In Helm, if a chart contains some object, and then you upgrade the chart to a newer version or values that don't include that object, then Helm will delete the object.  This would require that the Secret actually be part of the chart, like

```yaml
{{/* templates/cert-secret.yaml */}}
{{- if .Values.createSecret -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}-cert
...
{{ end -}}
```

If your chart already included this, and you ran `helm upgrade` with values that set `createSecret` to false, then Helm would delete the Secret.

If you're not in this situation, though – your chart references the Secret by name, but you expect something else to create it – then you'll also need to manually destroy it, maybe with `kubectl delete`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have edited the post to include my certificate.yaml file. Since, it appears to me that I have created the certificate and am just referencing it in ingress.yaml so your case applies to me, did I get that right ?

Comment: The edit shows exactly the pattern I suggest here; if you `helm upgrade --set certificate.enabled=false` I would expect Helm to delete the Secret, because it's no longer included in the release manifest.

Comment: Oh ok - so instead of deleting the `secretName: {{ .Values.name }}-cert` from ingress yaml I can just disable it from values file and that should also delete it from cluster. Haven't tested it, will try now and see if this works - thanks a lot.